# Module 'AFNetworking' has no member named 'request'

Tags: swift

I'm new to coding. Any help is appreciated!

I'm following a tutorial on how to set up Stripe in my project.
I integrated AFNetworking into my project, instead of Alamofire.
The tutorial uses Alamofire, so am I getting this error because I'm using AFNetworking?
I tried adding Alamofire to my pod file to make the tutorial easier for me to follow, but I keep getting the error, "No pod file found in directory", when the pod file is clearly in the directory (unless I'm finding it wrong).
Just a bit confused on how to fix this error.
What do I do??
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: AFNetworking and Alamofire are not the same, so you can't simply switch the name. If you are new to coding and the tutorial covers Alamofire, try to go with Alamofire first and replace it afterwards if needed. For [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) check the requirements, do you have the needed cocoapods version? What does your `Podfile` look like? Did you try with lower/higher version like `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alamofire** and **AFNetworking** are different *libraries*. Albeit coded by the same people. You won't be able to swap the class names because both libraries have different implementations. If you're coding in **Swift**, you should use Alamofire because it's also written in Swift.

You can keep both libraries in your project but it's like having two copies of something which do the same thing. You might want to migrate your code towards Alamofire if Stripe requires it, otherwise, you'll need to spend a bit of time re-kerjigging the Stripe tutorial code for AFNetworking.

Alamofile makes requests like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

and AFNetworking looks like this as it's written in **Objective-C**:

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://example.com";
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"baz": @[@1, @2, @3]};
[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];
```

---

For Cocoapods if ou want Alamofire in there, you'll need the line

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

under your application target. Alamofire has a couple of other revisions to it. If you're not using Swift 3, you'll want:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
```

in your Podfile, and then run pod install.

Comment: It says "no pod file found in the directory". I tried looking this up, but not sure what I'm doing wrong? My pod file seems to be in my directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you run the "pod install" command, in your Project directory to add Alamofire to your Xcode workspace? Is Xcode or Terminal giving you this message?